# Project not rebuilding when pressing F5

Tags: visual-studio

When running my project in Visual studio I always have to rebuild my project manually instead of it being rebuild automatically when pressing F5.
I am running VS2017.

I found some solutions but they weren't the problem as you can see in the pictures below.

[On run always build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6OmF.png)

[Make sure build is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To3cG.png)

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're experiencing?  VS by design only re-builds those projects that have had changes since the last build, which is that setting "On Run, when projects are out of date".  That only affects projects that are stale.  If there wasn't a change to it, there's no need to re-build it.

Comment: Currently I'm working on that project so I change it constantly. Every time I change something about the project I have to rebuild it manually in order to see the changes in my build during runtime.

Only pressing F5 shows me the old build, even after all the changes.

Comment: Strange.  Is your workspace mapped locally?  Is it being watched by a cloud service like Drive, DropBox, or OneDrive?

Comment: It is being mapped locally. It's only a small project.

And it suddenly started working again. I didnt change a thing.
After a few rebuilds I forgot to rebuild manually and I had a building error in my code. After fixing this the project rebuilded itself automatically again when I pressed F5.

Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help.